# edge detection via wavelet transform(dwt2)

Tags: matlab, image-processing, edge-detection, wavelet-transform

I want to detect edges of an image via dwt2. In fact I am going to simulate this [article](http://www.posterus.sk/?p=10983).

The first step of edge detection is based on replacing of all approximation coefficients with zeros. But when I replace the approximation coefficients with zero, the edges aren't similar to results seen in the article.

Here is my code:

```
clc;
clear all,close all

img=imread('2.png');
img=img(:,:,1);
imshow(img);

L = medfilt2(img,[3 3]);

L=im2double(L);
[A,H,V,D]=dwt2(L,'haar');

A=zeros(size(A));


Q1 = idwt2(A,H,V,D,'haar');

figure;
subplot(1,2,1);
imshow(img);
subplot(1,2,2); 
imshow(Q1);`


enter code here
clc;
clear all,close all

img=imread('2.png');
img=rgb2gray(img);
L = medfilt2(img,[3 3]);
t=graythresh(L);
b=im2bw(L,t);
[A,H,V,D]=dwt2(b,'haar');
A1=zeros(size(A));
Q1 = idwt2(A1,H,V,D,'haar');
figure;
subplot(1,2,1);
imshow(img);
subplot(1,2,2);
imshow(Q1);
```

Comment: It could be many things.  Did you try it on the image in the link specifically?  Also, did you try other wavelets, not just Haar?  I've tried it on some images and it does work, but the edges aren't emphasized as much.

Comment: thank.in the link,section 2.1.1,image 'b' obtained by replacing zero and haar func.(b) "Edges found by
replacing approximation coe±cients by zeros (using Haar wavelet function)"

Comment: perhaps it caused by this line:"Image thresholding and median filtering were used for images preprocessing". and i do not use these operators

Comment: Maybe.  Try using those operators.

Comment: can you help me on it?

Comment: You can try using `im2bw` and `graythresh` to threshold your image.  Use `medfilt` first, then use `im2bw/graythresh`, then try the DWT mechanism on this filtered result.

Comment: Place the edits in your post.  Don't put them in comments.  We can't read code in comments past a couple of lines.

Comment: So does it work or not?

Comment: thanks.it work,but not the same as in the link.

Comment: Out of ideas. sorry.  Maybe you should contact the original author.

Comment: he/she do not answer. which one of operator can smooth edges?excusme

Comment: Google: "smooth edges image processing": http://www.google.com/#q=smooth+edges+image+processing

Comment: no,no,no....it is not help

Comment: no problem. good luck.may god help you.:)))))

Comment: :)   :)   :)  :)  :)   :)